# Python: How to sort a list of Rect objects?

Tags: python, sorting, pymupdf

I made a pdf reader that searches for a specific value and makes a list. I use PymuPDF which is incredible.
So now I have this list and I would like to sort it with the following logic:

1. first Rect is the top, left most Rect
2. each following Rect is the closest Rect to the previous Rect

I tried sort() but it returns that Rect object cannot be < to another Rect object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `list.sort` won't work for this. You need to write your own function, calling `min` repeatedly to minimise the distance between the next Rect and the current Rect.

Comment: @Dat_guy_who_hangs_out - suppose that the topmost Rect isn't the same as the leftmost Rect. What should the first item in the result be in that case?

Comment: It depends a little what is contained in those rects, but usually you have boundary boxes of text or images, and you want them in Western reading sequence top-left to bottom right. In these cases best sort ascending by (1) rect bottom, (2) rect left. The sort key then would be `key=lambda rect: (rect.y1, rect.x0)` or `key=lambda rect: (rect[3], rect[0])` if you just have a tuple of the bbox.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "closest"?

Comment: This needs a good example.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` won't work for this.

`list.sort` can only sort item when it makes sense to compare them with `<`. For instance, if you wanted to sort the rectangles from top to bottom and from left to right, then `list.sort` would be perfect. But what you want is more complex.

You can write your own function, using `min` repeatedly to find the next rectangle that minimises the distance with the current rectangle.

Because of the need to remove rectangles from the list repeatedly, I suggest storing the yet_unsorted rects into a `set` rather than a `list`.

You also need to define what is the "distance between two rects", so that looking for the next closest rect makes sense. I'm not aware of such a function in pymupdf, so I wrote one.

```py
from itertools import product

# square of the distance
# between the closest corner of a to the closest corner of b
def sqdist(a, b):
    return min((xa-xb)**2 + (ya-yb)**2
               for xa, ya, xb, yb
               in product((a.x0, a.x1), (a.y0, a.y1), (b.x0, b.x1), (b.y0, b.y1)))

def find_path(rects):
    remaining_rects = set(rects)
    current_rect = min(remaining_rects, key=lambda r: r.x0 ** 2 + r.y0 ** 2)
    sorted_rects = [current_rect]
    remaining_rects.remove(current_rect)
    while remaining_rects:
        next_rect = min(remaining_rects, key=lambda r: sqdist(current_rect, r))
        sorted_rects.append(next_rect)
        remaining_rects.remove(next_rect)
        current_rect = next_rect
    return sorted_rects
```

Disclaimer: This is untested! I normally test my functions before posting answers, but you didn't provide an example list of rectangles, and I'm a bit too lazy tonight to make up one.

Comment: @KellyBundy I interpreted "closest" quite literally, in the geometrical sense. My point was that library pymupdf does not provide a function "distance between two Rect objects", we have to write our own, so I did write one. But that indeed gives the OP an opportunity to wonder whether they really want the "closest" rectangle in the geometrical sense.

Comment: @KellyBundy Also, my first idea when I read the question was that this constraint to always select the next closest rectangle in a greedy way sounds quite arbitrary; perhaps what the OP would really want is the shortest path that goes through all rectangles.

Comment: @KellyBundy Also note that the function I wrote is only an approximation of the geometrical distance; in particular it doesn't return 0 unless two corners touch, whereas the true geometrical distance would be zero for two rectangles whose side touch or who overlap, even if they don't have touching corners.

Comment: @Stef is correct it is a geometrical distance, I was thinking the function could be a distance from the first point in a rect object, making it a distance between 2 points and instead of 2 rect.